# Exchange 2010 powershell - select custom attributes

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, powershell

How do I select the custom attribute from the Exchange powershell command get-mailboxstatistics?  I would have expected to use something along the lines of

```
get-mailboxstatistics -server dbserver | select DisplayName, ItemCount, {$_.TotalItemSize.value.toMB()}, Database, ***customattribute3*** | export-csv c:\allusers.csv -encoding "unicode"
```

Is extracting a custom attribute possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute "CustomAttribute" is part of the Get-Mailbox Cmdlet, so I'd suggest to incorporate this Cmdlet in your script.